# Mouseleave event not firing when mouse leaves while scrolling

Tags: angular

I have a simple div with a (mouseleave) trigger, problem is, if i scroll , thus the mouse leaving the div without actually moving, the event is not fired.

i tried using mouse out but that doesn't seem to make a difference in this case.

```
<div id="dismiss" (mouseleave)="show = false">
<img src="url" *ngIf="show" />

it works well except when i scroll past the dismiss div
```

Comment: Without any further investigation, I guess you'll have to use rxjs operators to combine scroll and mouseleave events. And likely detect whether, on scroll event, the mouse is still over your component. I'm not at home now, or I'd give it a shot on stackblitz.

Comment: @jpavel in the end i couldn't figure out, so i just did whole different approach, i changed the whole html for it but it gets the job, i did find some interesting articles where people got creative on how to fix undetected mouseleave events